# Is there any way to change values for created user from MainClass?

Tags: java, constructor, hashmap

I can't change values for the object which I created in Main class.

It uses java jre 8. I've tried it on eclipse IDE.

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

```
public static HashMap<String,Data> PlayerData = new HashMap<String,Data>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PlayerData.put("User1", new Data("User1","Password1",21));
    PlayerData.get("User1").giveInformation();
    PlayerData.get("User1").setAge(78);
    try{
        PlayerData.get("User1").giveInformation();
    }catch(NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }
}
```

}

class Data {

```
private String Name;
private String Password;
private int Age;

public Data(String Name, String Password, int Age) {
    this.setName(Name);
    this.setPassword(Password);
    this.setAge(Age);
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    Password = password;
}

public int getAge() {
    return Age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    Age = age;
}

public void giveInformation() {
    System.out.println("Name: " + this.Name);
    System.out.println("Password: " + this.Password);
    System.out.println("Age: " + this.Age);
}
```

}
I wanted to run `giveInformation()` method to see changed calues but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Steps: 1) get the object form the map, using a .`get(...)` method call, 2) call a "setter" method on the object obtained to change its state (your Data class has none???). 3) done.

Comment: Since all attributes are private (as they should be) and no [mutator methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) are implemented, a `Data` instance is effectively [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) (which is not a bad thing by the way). So no, after object creation, you cannot change the values (without [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/index.html)).

Comment: side note: OK to have println's in the constructor when debugging, such as calling `giveInformation()` from the constructor, but you will want to remove it from the production code.

Comment: So solution: give Data some setter methods ***if*** you want one or more of its fields to be mutable.

Comment: @Turing85 , @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels thanks for your help.

Comment: So does this code now work? Or if still having problems, please elaborate on the problems. Side note 2: Never catch NullPointerExceptions (NPE) as you're doing. That just means that you're allowing broken code.

Comment: Side note 3: you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: Yes it works well.